# XSLT keep tag only once and also sort

Tags: sorting, xslt-1.0

I am trying to accomplish the below logic. What I need is tag Y should occur only once as provided in the expected output; and also, sort the input  sections based on tag B. See expected output. 31’s should come first, then 61’s and then 91’s

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am using XSL version 1.0

Sample Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
               <Y>Sample</Y>
               <Detail>
                              <A>351</A>
                              <B>61</B>
                              <C>Adjustment</C>
                              <D>adj1</D>
               </Detail>
               <Y>Sample</Y>
               <Detail>
                              <A>351</A>
                              <B>31</B>
                              <C>Receipt</C>
                              <D>rcpt1</D>
               </Detail>
               <Y>Sample</Y>
               <Detail>
                              <A>351</A>
                              <B>91</B>
                              <C>Putaway</C>
                              <D>put1</D>
               </Detail>
               <Y>Sample</Y>
               <Detail>
                              <A>351</A>
                              <B>31</B>
                              <C>Receipt</C>
                              <D>rcpt2</D>
               </Detail>
</Root>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
               <Y>Sample</Y>
               <Detail>
                              <A>351</A>
                              <B>31</B>
                              <C>Receipt</C>
                              <D>rcpt1</D>
               </Detail>
               <Detail>
                              <A>351</A>
                              <B>31</B>
                              <C>Receipt</C>
                              <D>rcpt2</D>
               </Detail>
               <Detail>
                              <A>351</A>
                              <B>61</B>
                              <C>Adjustment</C>
                              <D>adj1</D>
               </Detail>
               <Detail>
                              <A>351</A>
                              <B>91</B>
                              <C>Putaway</C>
                              <D>put1</D>
               </Detail>
</Root>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Simply output the `<Y>Sample</Y>` once in the result tree, and copy rest of the Detail nodes by sorting based on node B.

Comment: Thanks. I got this to work by using <xsl:sort select="B" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>